# I would like to purchase the rights to the software my company created but no longer wishes to maintain or use

Tags: software, intellectual-property, exit-planning

I work for a firm which has a large in-house development arm. We have a small software package which was written by one guy 6 years ago. This software is currently used in production but the guy who wrote it was let go about 2 years ago.

The software is a very useful piece of software, in my opinion, and I have been maintaining it since this time last year. Management is looking to decommission it in favor of a vendor supported product, and so I would like to approach my employer about purchasing the rights to the software as part of an exit package in the future.

The software does not compete with my employer in any way, as its simply a tool they use for configuration reporting, and so I think they may be willing to consider selling me the rights to it when I leave if I ask and negotiate in good faith.

I'm just not certain of how to go about approaching the subject, and would appreciate insight from anyone who has attempted or successfully completed an acquisition of IP from their employer.

Comment: Which country do you live in?

Comment: I live in the United States

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would just point out to you that, if it is a large company, it is ***incredibly*** unlikely they would do this.

- The small amount of money to them would be totally irrelevant, and
- The legal hassle and possible downsides on their front would be enormous.

(An analogy: say you are leaving a big company and you want to buy *an office chair* you notice they no longer need. It is literally impossible to do this, there would be no mechanism for it, it would cost them $200,000 in legal fees to figure out liability and what the other party is "up to" in buying their old chairs, and so on.)

Next point,

- **Do not mention this to them in any way at all.** It will instantly signal you are leaving the company. Forget it and set it aside. Until/if you literally have left.

Next point,

- You may be **drastically overthinking this**. If it's just "an approach" to some sort of reporting thing, go ahead and take that approach again in new software, as certainly 10,000 other projects have taken that approach anyway.  (Self-evidently and obviously, don't "copy and paste some lines of their code" - but you would never do that anyway, source that is 10 years old is worthless and you just rewrite the approach anyway.)

The biggest company on Earth exists for the extremely simple reason that Steve Jobs copied every. single. detail. of Xerox's inventions regarding computers, but he didn't like "copy and paste the code".  So!

Comment: Steve Jobs signed a deal where he and his team could visit Xerox and look at everything, in exchange for a significant number of stock options. Xerox sold the shares very quickly with barely any profit. And I must say, a Mac in 1984 didn't like anything like a Xerox Star for example.

Comment: (Xerox sued Apple for copying the ideas.)  Sure - It was really just an analogy, an example, Gnash.  Whether or not "Steve Jobs stole it all from PARC" is the subject of endless major books, articles, autobiographies, etc and can't be decided in a quick list comment eh!

Comment: This answer is bizarre.  Companies regularly sell off unused equipment, including office chairs, and it doesn't have to be any more complicated than writing a receipt and depositing $20 in the petty cash box.  Selling software is more unusual, but definitely not unheard of.

Answer (score 5):

Leave any mention until after you're ready to resign.

At that point it may have already been decommissioned which will potentially make things easier. Also mentioning it beforehand is basically saying you want to leave the company. You shouldn't do this until you are going to leave because they might just find a replacement and get rid of you, or the work dynamic may change for the worse.

Once you're good to go, then just ask. The worst that can happen is they say no.

Answer (score 3):

Obvious Answer: Ask.

If you don't know who to ask, start with your direct superior and work yourself upwards until you find someone who feels responsible for that software license. If the answer is No, ask for reasons and try to address the problems your manager may see.

Comment: Out of curiosity: If no one on OP's current company feels responsible, would that imply that the original author of the code could claim the copyrights?

Comment: @LustLudo The original author wrote it for the company, so the company has all rights. If no manager from direct lead up to CEO feels responsible about the license, I would draft a licensing contract up myself and just hand it to the CEO for signature. If no one cares it can't be a problem, right? ;)

Comment: Makes a lot of sense. I wonder if the original code had copyrights in the files. Maybe OP can let us know?

Comment: Whatever you do **do not ask**.  Once you have *left the company* you might ask.

Comment: I left the company. They are still using the product, to be decommissioned later this year at some point. I did not ask, and don't plan to anymore. I've moved on from this idea. Good question, but no, there were no copyright files since it was developed for the company.